# Windows 7 / Terminal Services RemoteApp

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-terminal-services, remoteapp

Please, show me a way to set up Windows 7 machine to use only one app (internet explorer) to access remotely from another machine - similar to TS RemoteApp, which is only for Windows Server platforms as I understand...

Comment: Please read FAQ, this is only for users in a professional capacity... instead post in http://superuser.com/.

Comment: @ColdT There are any number of professional situations where this could be useful. One that comes to mind is letting users remote-connect to their desktop for *just one app*. (Not saying doing so is a good idea by any stretch of the imagination, but I don't see anything in this question that indicates it's a "home use" question...)

Comment: Cold T, this is more a professional question because it refers to system administration more than just superuser'ing :D my task is to allow remote accessing to IE to test web pages having only linux on my machine and only windows on the remote one. and if you can't help or don't know the answer you better not post comments...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you are using a desktop version of Windows 7 which has Remote Desktop (non-home version) you can make a couple of changes in the registry and the .rdp file to enable RemoteApp.  You do not need to use Windows Server.  I do this on my HTPC which runs Windows 7 Ultimate.

It's a little too involved for me to summarise the process here, so [here is a link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210117115603/http://geekswithblogs.net/twickers/archive/2009/12/18/137048.aspx) to where I first learnt how to do this, and [here is tool](https://sites.google.com/site/kimknight/remoteapptool), which I just found out about, which make it much easier.

[image: RemoteApp Tool]

Comment: Small correction, it's not enough to have a non-Home version, Windows 7/8/10 Pro don't support RemoteApps.

Comment: @Neowizard It does. Read the first link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GoGlobal from Graphon. It does like rdp/Citrix, and can be installed on workstation. Yes, multiple users can use it without buying RDP/TSE license.

Free trial here: http://www.graphon.com/products-and-solutions/go-global-windows